# Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED in npm while posting data to HTTPS Api

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, npm

I am new to nodejs.
While sending post data to **https** server, 
(https://abc.example.com/xyz/contactUs/adds)
I am getting error as below:

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1370:32)
    at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:223:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:213:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
```

I am able to send post data on **http** server successfully.
I have configured SSL with aws, but this **https** post method is not working and throwing error as above.
I am using purely Nodejs npm for running website.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have similar issue with java. In my case I have `dev` server with self-signed cerificate, and to work with it (to send reqests from `localhost` to `dev` server) I get puliblic key from `dev` server and put it into `cacerts` file. `cacerts` file contain trusted sertificates for java. In your case, try to google something like `ssl certificate storage nodejs` or `cacerts for nodejs` or something similar.

Comment: Test the connection with something else, like `openssl s_client -connect` to see if you have trust issues, or the other server's cert is improperly installed.  Note also that when importing your own certificate into IAM (and possibly ACM, which now also supports importing your own 3rd party certificates) will tell you the certificate chain is "optional."  It is in fact almost never optional.